# I am working on an API for a class I am in and I have a cannot convert error

Tags: c#

I am working on an API and I have an error that says "cannot convert from "HolidayChallenge.Models.Ornament.Ornament2Edit to HolidayChallenge.Data.Ornament2". The code follows:

```
[Route("api/Ornament2/Update")]
        public IHttpActionResult Put(Ornament2Edit ornament2)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            var service = CreateOrnament2Service();
            if (!service.UpdateOrnament(ornament2)) //This is the line the error is on
            {
                return InternalServerError();
            }
            return Ok("Your Ornament was updated!");
```

I am not sure how to fix this one. I have figured a lot of similar ones out but this one is fighting me. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.
**Update to question**
OrnamentEdit:

```
namespace HolidayChallenge.Models.Ornament
{
    public class Ornament2Edit
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int TreeId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Ornament2:

```
namespace HolidayChallenge.Data
{
    public class Ornament2
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Ornament2> Ornaments { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ChristmasTree")]
        public int TreeId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public virtual ChristmasTree ChristmasTree { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Ornament2Service:

```
 public bool UpdateOrnament(Ornament2 model)
        {
            using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                var entity =
                    ctx
                        .Ornaments
                        .Single(e => e.Id == model.Id && e.UserId == _userId);
                entity.Id = model.Id;
                entity.Description = model.Description;
                entity.TreeId = model.TreeId;

                return ctx.SaveChanges() == 1;
            }
        }
```

Comment: The service's `UpdateOrnament` method accepts a `Ornament2` type but you're trying to pass the `Ornament2Edit` type. You'll need to pass the correct type to the method.

Comment: Show the definitions of Ornament2 and Ornament2Edit

Comment: Ornament2Edit:
namespace HolidayChallenge.Models.Ornament
{
    public class Ornament2Edit
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int TreeId { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: Ornament2:
public class Ornament2
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Ornament2> Ornaments { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ChristmasTree")]
        public int TreeId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public virtual ChristmasTree ChristmasTree { get; set; }
    }

Comment: You see that "Edit" word under the questionn.. Please click it and add new information into the question. Don't post swathes of code into comments; as you can see it turns into a barely comprehensible mess

Answer (score 0):

your Service input is **Ornament2** object but you pass an **Ornament2Edit** object and this causes the error. you must pass an object with the correct type.